# ListView in Avalonia UI

Tags: c#, avaloniaui

Unfortunately Avalonia UI is still behind WPF and `ListView` is missing. I have found out one alternative, `ItemsRepeater`, but its very basic and not interactive. Apparently you can make it interactive, but I have to yet found an example that takes less than 200 lines of code and actually works. I just refuse to believe no one made something that works as simply as `ListView` in WPF.

I want to display `List` of custom data model (property A and B etc), and I'm really tempted to just use `DataGrid`. Will be ugly, but it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://github.com/wieslawsoltes/DataBox it's very simple control with columns based on ListBox